# How do you remove Mirror and SubSurface seams?

Tags: mirror

I'm fairly new to Blender and am trying to make a human face mesh using the Mirror and Subdivision Surface modifiers. When I attempt to do so, the result shows this seam in the mesh and does not have the mirror align properly, as well as the subsurface creating a rip in the center mouth. How do I resolve this issue?[image]

File:
[image]

Comment: Upload you file: should be a problem of "Clipping" . . . you didn't tick it

Comment: How do I upload the file? Or do I need to paste a download link?

Also, is it too late to tick Clipping?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/
upload your file will help a lot; then we will understand if we are late or not ;)

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15347/how-to-lock-center-vertices-with-mirror-modifier and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh

Comment: Thanks for the link. Uploaded file now. I tried to fix what I could with the seam by using the Clipping so far

Edit: I got it all removed! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MrZak Why not mark this question as a duplicate of that second link? It's exactly the same.

Comment: @Fuboski: You should provide that as an answer as it solved the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments, I've got it to work now! Issue was I needed to tick Clipping then apply Subsurf after the Mirror modifier.

Comment: Accept this as your answer to your question for future users who come asking the same problem. :)

Comment: will do. Says I need to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer though

Comment: Come back in two days then, don't forget!

Comment: You should Fuboski give the possibility to answer and mark that as answered as he pointed you in the correct direction and should earn the reputation for it ;-)

Comment: That's an option too. Fuboski, have your comment as an answer and I'll mark it :)