# The line of symmetry move when I adjust the size

Tags: modeling

I created a cube and then 'ctrl + R' to create a line of symmetry for the cube (Vertical). Then I 'x' to delete the left vertical and add a modifier of mirror so that the cube could be adjust by only changing one side. But when i try to adjust the size by 's', the line of symmetry will move with other line as well, which I did not expect to happen. As shown:
[image]

But actually I want something like this:
[image]

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Either Clipping isn't enabled in Mirror modifier settings or one or several vertices were already past mirror plane so Clipping didn't get them. Enable it and move vertices a bit so they stick to the mirror plane (or select all vertices on the mirror plane and scale them to 0 by axis perpendicular to mirror plane, X in your case, etc). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15347/how-to-lock-center-vertices-with-mirror-modifier

Comment: You could scale with reference to the 3d cursor, where the cursor is at the 0 point on the desired axis

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to fix weird mirroring is to create a **new empty** and use that as your line of symmetry by selecting it under **Mirror Object**

[image]

If it doesn't work as you expect this is usually faster than messing around with whatever it is.